# Milchigs (dairy) on Shavuos - when is the proper time?

Tags: halacha, minhag, food, shavuos, dairy

When is the proper time to eat dairy on Shavuos? (night meal, day meal, prior to day meal, Shul Kiddush)

Comment: The rama says explicitly the custom is to have dairy on the first day of shavuos

Comment: @double aa sounds like a good answer

Comment: It's amazing that I've read that rama a dozen times and only noticed this today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many different minhagim when it comes to Milchigs on Shvous. I know the Yekehs have a milchig meal at night. Many people have the Minhag to eat a Milchig meal by day. The chassidim on the other hand, will have some milchigs after kiddush (by day) and then wait half an hour before eating a full fleishig meal. (The logic being that a Seudah's yom tov needs to be with meat).

Comment: Who has a milchig seudah by day?

Answer (score 2):

according to the rema oc 494,3 who first cites this minhag - and according to the machatzis hasehekel there - 7, one needs to have separate breads to be yotzei the korban shni halechem - that means a milchig meal followed by a fleishig meal is proper.
r m feinstein  - Shu”t Igros Moshe (O.C. vol. 1, 160) wrote that this is the best way to go as well.

see relevant article [here](http://ohr.edu/5154)

Answer (score 0):

I heard of a Chasidic Rebbe whose minhag on Shavous was to mix his morning tea with a spoon that was ***milchig ben-yomo***.

So I guess you can be yotze with anything from there and beyond :).

Comment: Would this render the tea milchig?

Comment: @Curiouser To the extent that you wouldn't drink the tea and eat meat at the same time.

Comment: @DavidPerlman nat-bar-nat on a cli sheini (that could be buttel b'shishim -- if spoon small enough relative to drink) to not eat at the SAME TIME? *maybe* not the same time mamash in ones mouth, but certainly couldn't eat at the same seudah

Comment: @Yehoshua would you, at a fleishig meal, take a milchig spoon, ben-yomo or not, to mix your tea?

Comment: @DavidPerlman I wouldn't mind that at all. I wouldn't go out of my way to do so, but it's not a problem if that's what was available.

Comment: I'm fairly certain what you heard must have been a joke and not real

Comment: Definitely JOKE